# Freeing an array of structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct, free, sigabrt

I have the following code, I need to free an array of the d_array structure after using it and I get always SiGABRT.

```
typedef struct d_array
{
  int len;
  double * content;
} d_array;


quantile(d_array arr,  d_array percentages, d_array borders )
{
  int i;

  d_array temp_arr;

  temp_arr.content =(double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*arr.len);
  memcpy(temp_arr.content, arr.content, sizeof(double)*arr.len);

  qsort(temp_arr.content, arr.len, sizeof(double), d_compare);

  double med = arr.content[(int)(arr.len/2)];

  for(i=0; i< percentages.len; i++)
   {
    borders.content[i] = temp_arr.content[(int)(100*(percentages.content[i]))];
   }

  free(temp_arr.content);

  }
```

Comment: You need to make a "destructor" function (and you should make some "constructor" function as well). You might want (with C99) instead to use a flexible array member like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23433573/841108)

Comment: Why you use a new array just for a double value? Why not use double *temp? Easier and less clutter.

Comment: @Igor: because he wants to keep the array size. And you mean `double`, not `float` !!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What size? Also `arr.len = arr.len;` line does nothing.

Comment: Your code could be improved a bit (e.g., declare `quantile()` as `void`, remove the redundant statement `arr.len = arr.len;`, spell "percentage" properly), but I can't see any memory leaks here. I think your problem lies elsewhere. Also, why is this question tagged as [tag:segmentation-fault]?

Comment: What does arr.len in this line do? Why is it needed? `memcpy(temp_arr.content, arr.content, sizeof(double)*arr.len);`

Comment: I am sorry, I know it has some mistakes It is not finished yet , I have to add interpolation function to it, but the problem is that I cannot free the memory allocated to the content field of the structure.

Comment: @Igor arr.len is length of array //items number// , pozdrav druze ;)

Comment: Pozdrav :) Yeah, I know, but I don't think that multiplying with arr.len is needed in that case. If you could include your main function it would be great, because it would help in debugging.

Comment: Meanwhile, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3194340 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4931123/3194340

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tagging "Segmentation-fault", I believe you are facing a crash of the program with signal "segmentation-fault". You might need to check the value of percentages.content[i] in the below code. The 100 * that value might be going beyond what was allocated for temp_arr.content.

> borders.content[i] =
>   temp_arr.content[(int)(100*(pecentages.content[i]))];

As far as memory leak, i dont find anything in this function.

Comment: you are right, the problem is SIGABRT not memory leak it is my fault. But it still does not work. Consider it is borders.content[5]=1;

Comment: Please add a check before borders.content[i] assignment like below:

`if((100 * pecentages.content[i]) > arr.len)
{
     printf ("Array size exceeded\n");
     return;
}`
and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function finished but the free is working now because I added **struct** before the declaration of temp_arr:
This could be helpful for other people maybe:

```
 void quantile(d_array arr,  d_array percentages, d_array borders ) 
 {
 int i;
 struct d_array temp_arr;

 temp_arr.content = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*(arr.len+2));
 memcpy(temp_arr.content+1, arr.content, sizeof(double)*arr.len);
 t_d(temp_arr.content, 25);
 qsort(temp_arr.content+1, arr.len, sizeof(double), d_compare);
 t_d(temp_arr.content, 25);

 temp_arr.content[0] = temp_arr.content[1];
 temp_arr.content[arr.len+1] = temp_arr.content[arr.len];
 t_d(temp_arr.content, 25);


 d_array q;
 q.len = arr.len+2;
 q.content = malloc(sizeof(double)*(arr.len+2));

 q.content[0] = 0;
 q.content[1] = 100*0.5/arr.len;
 q.content[arr.len+1] = 100;

 for(i=2; i<arr.len+1 ;i++)
   q.content[i] = (q.content[i-1] + (double)100/arr.len);

 int indx=0;
 double elem=0;

 for(i=0; i< percentages.len; i++)
 {

   find(q, percentages.content[i]*100, '>', &indx,  &elem);

   if (temp_arr.content[indx] == temp_arr.content[indx-1] )
     borders.content[i] = temp_arr.content[indx-1];
   else
     borders.content[i] = temp_arr.content[indx-1] + (percentages.content[i]*100 -    q.content[indx-1])*(temp_arr.content[indx]-temp_arr.content[indx-1])/(q.content[indx]-q.content[indx-1]) ;

 }
         free(temp_arr.content);
   }
find function:
int find(d_array mat, double el, char op, int *indx, double * eee)
{
  int i;
  if (op=='>')
   for(i=0;i<mat.len ;i++)
    if (mat.content[i]>el)
       {
        *indx = i;
        *eee= mat.content[i];
        return 0;
       }
  else if(op=='=')
   for(i=0;i<mat.len ;i++)
    if (mat.content[i] == el)
       {
        *indx = i;
        *eee = mat.content[i];
        return 0;
       }
  else if(op=='<')
   for(i=0;i<mat.len ;i++)
    if (mat.content[i] < el)
       {
        *indx = i;
        *eee = mat.content[i];
        return 0;
       }
   return 1;

}
```

and:
    struct d_array
    { double *content
      int len
    } d_array;

the call is :
       double test_sig[] = {1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0,51.0, 20.0, 514.0, 2.0, 0.0, 151.0, 20.0, 51.0, 0.0, 016.0, 05.0};
          struct d_array  pecentages;
          pecentages.content=malloc(sizeof(double)*5);
          pecentages.len=5;

```
      struct d_array  borders;
      borders.content=malloc(sizeof(double)*5);
      borders.len=5;

      mat.content = test_sig;
      pecentages.content[0] = 0.1;
      pecentages.content[1] = 0.2;
      pecentages.content[2] = 0.5;
      pecentages.content[3] = 0.8;
      pecentages.content[4] = 0.9;
      quantile( mat, pecentages, borders );
```