# malloc and free: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I've been trying to be more "memory-aware" in my C programming when I found out about the `malloc` method and similar memory management methods. However, when I tried to use `realloc` to allocate as little memory as possible to a `char*` instance in my program, I found that it wasn't holding as much data as I thought it would.

Here is my code:

```
int foo(char * arg){
    if(condition){
        //code here
    }else if(other_condition){
        char * cmd = malloc(5);
        fgets(cmd,sizeof(cmd),stdin);
        //more code here
        if(another_condition){
            //more code
            cmd = realloc(cmd,new_size) //once in this if block, but also once in another block
            fgets(cmd,sizeof(cmd),stdin);
            //more code
        }
        //more else-if blocks here
        free(cmd)
    }
    //more else-if blocks here
}
```

To be specific, in the above code snippet, `new_size` was 255, although it has been set to other sizes in other places. The problem is that when I run the program I only get 7 letters of my input.

Example output:

```
...
Enter filename: document1
Loading file "documen"
Load failed
...
(here the next time fgets is called it fails because "t1" is not valid input for the program)
```

I understand that it's receiving `"t1"` because I'm not clearing the input buffer, but what I want to solve is the fact that I'm only receiving the first 7 characters of the input. If I call `sizeof(cmd)` in the middle, it tells me that the memory occupied by `cmd` is 8. I also tried allocating the memory using `char * cmd = malloc(5 * sizeof(char))` and `cmd = realloc(cmd,255 * sizeof(char))` but it didn't solve the problem. I should probably mention that if I declare the variable using the `char cmd[255]` syntax and I don't call `malloc`, `realloc`, or `free` anywhere this problem no longer comes up.

Comment: If you're on a platform that supports [GNU `getline()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) you might want to consider using it - it helps manage the dynamic allocation of the buffer for lines of input (though you will still need a variable to track the size).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478240/how-i-return-the-size-of-the-pointer-that-i-have-allocate-with-malloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fgets(cmd,sizeof(cmd),stdin);
```

Here `cmd` is a `char*` instead of a `char[]`. Thus, its size is always the size of a pointer, instead of the array size.

You should keep track of the chunk size allocated by yourself.

Comment: Is there a way to use `malloc` with `char[]`? If I declare the variable with `char cmd[] = malloc(255)` it says the "array initializer must be an initializer list or a string literal". Are there other solutions? Is the only way to free `cmd`'s memory to wait for it to go out of scope?

Comment: No. The general rule of thumb is that you should explicitly know (and usually keep - in a variable or a field) the size of `malloc`-ed data. You might consider using flexible array members like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23433573/841108)

Comment: @Arc676 `char cmd[255];` instead of `char cmd[] = malloc(255);`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Is that the only way? Using your method would mean that `cmd` will automatically be released when it goes out of scope, but I would have no control over when it is released right?

Comment: Yes that's right. If you want control over when it is freed then use the malloc version.

Comment: Using the `malloc` version is what is causing this problem.

Comment: So you have two options, and if you want the option that includes the flexibility you get by using `malloc()` you'll have to track the allocation size yourself.

Comment: But how do I allocate to `char[]` using `malloc`?

Comment: That's not an option.